# CakePHP JsHelper - Getting Response and Printing it in View

Tags: ajax, json, cakephp

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to get the response from below code which is located in the Controller back in the View:

```
   if ($this->request->isAjax()){
        Configure::write ( 'debug', 0 );
        $this->autoRender = 0;
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $results = "My Data";
        echo json_encode($results);
    }

    //tried doing this and it doesn't work
    $this->set('results',$results);
```

I just want be able to access the data that is in the $results variable back in my View.

Comment: what does your view code making the request look like?

Comment: $autoRender is usually boolean - not int. but it should not matter.. would be cleaner, though.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your entire method, it would be logical that nothing is shown in your view. Since you've disabled autoRendering with:

```
$this->autoRender = 0;
```

You need to manually render your view at some point, using:

```
$this->render('view');
```

Where `view` is the actual name of the view you want to render. Otherwise, you'll just get a blank page.

Also note that you're setting `$results` within your `isAjax()` check, but you set it to your view outside that check, so you will get an undefined variable error if a "regular" call (non-ajax) is made to your controller action.

Comment: I'm setting autoRender to false because I don't want render anything, all I want to do is store the data that is returned by the ajax response and then send it back to the view. Also, I'm doing $this->set(); inside the isAjax() check, above is just an example code.

I haven't run into to this problem until I started using JsHelper.

Comment: @Walter It sounds like you're looking for a `$this->Js->request` then. Check [the documenation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper::request) on this.